# Check which user logged in in PHP

Tags: php, android, xcode, authentication

I am new in php and I an making an application on iPhone that has a username and password for each user, and users are able to register. I would like to know if there are a lot of users, how can I check which user is logged in ?

When the user logged in their information will be displayed.

I am currently using

```
if ($id == 1)
{
   //command
}
if ($id == 2)
{
   //command
}
else
   //command
```

Is there a possible way to check which user is logged in without having to do the if else statement?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need to know which user logged in?

Comment: @strmstn Because their information will be displayed not other user's, like instagram or Facebook

Comment: Then you should probably use the ID to load the appropriate information from a database

Comment: @strmstn That is exactly what I asked = =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to keep last user action time in database. Then select users, which did last action, for example, in last 10 minutes and track them as online users.